# Identify this plant and fruit

Tags: identification

[image]

Please see the photo. Any idea what the plant is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People will often only notice the [rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_hip) when it is in blossom. This is what it looks like after the flowers fruit. There are some recipes that you'll find that need rose hip.

Answer (score 1):

It's a rose, possibly Rosa rugosa, though there are others which produce large, bright red hips. The hips are formed after the flowers have gone and are actually seed pods; some roses are grown for their decorative hips rather than their flowers. Image of the flower and the hips of rosa rugosa here https://www.davidaustinroses.com/eu/r-rugosa